# Where is data in angularjs http post request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm not sure if I'm just being dumb but here goes. I'm trying to send data to my server through a angularjs button which runs a function with HTTP post request. However I'm not sure where the data is stored in the request. This is my button function:

```
 <script>
        var app = angular.module('buttonApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
           $scope.myFunc = function(url) {
               console.log("func called");
               $http({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: url,
                  data: 'some data'
               }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
               }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log("Failed connection");
               });
           }
       });
    </script>
```

Here is my server code:

```
app.post('/buttonPressed', function(req, res){
  button = true;
  console.log(req);
  res.send("success");
});
```

If I console.log the 'req' I get a huge JSON structure where I can't find any reference to 'data' that I'm looking for. Am I on completely the wrong track?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? If you just need the sent JSON params I'd store them in a local variable right before the $http request.

The server response is usually in `response.data` (given that correct headers are set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use middilware

```
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

then

```
app.post('/buttonPressed', function(req, res){
  button = true;
  req.body; //get the body parameter (POST data)

  res.send("success");
});
```

It will give the post data sent in body

Comment: Thanks man, that has made things a lot easier. Though apparently now it's just app.use(bodyParser());